Is it right to store/ hard code API Key, SK Key, api token, Security key. Doesn't this expose the access to db?
Storing in variable example Firebase API Key
const String apiKey = "12345-ABCDE-SecretKey";

Storing fetched token from API in sharef preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('apiKey', '12345-abcde-67890');

Logging Key for testing and leaving them with release build
debugPrint("API Key: 12345-abcde-67890");

Including in env variable without encryption or declaring as global variable.
export API_KEY="12345-abcde-67890"


For local storage it's better to use flutter_secure_storage package to encrypt the data. To manage API in your cache it's better to use flutter_dotenv package to store all keys in .env file and define it in gitignore file. By this approach your keys won't be disclosed by git.
